# Detecting questions in text

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text, nlp, analytics

I have a project where I need to analyze a text to extract some information if the user who post this text need help in something or not, I tried to use sentiment analysis but it didn't work as expected, my idea was to get the negative post and extract the main words in the post and suggest to him some articles about that subject, if there is another way that can help me please post it below and thanks.

for the dataset i useed, it was a dataset for sentiment analyze, but now I found that it's not working and I need a dataset use for this subject.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired output? What is the size of your training data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this topic I found that this field in machine learning is called `"Natural Language Questions"` it's a field where machine learning models trained to detect questions in text and suggesting answer for them based on data set you are working with, check this [article](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C18-1275) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the NLP methods before processing the sentiment analysis. Use the TFIDF, Word2Vector to create vectors on the given dataset. And them try the sentiment analysis. You may also need glove vector for the conducting analysis.